# Present Perfect does it mean till now?

Tags: present-perfect

Source: https://smallbusiness.chron.com/delete-photo-folders-iphone-54223.html

Tyson Cliffton has been writing professionally since 2001. *His work has been published at thealestle.com and KMOX.com.*
Cliffton earned a Bachelor of Science in mass communications from Southern Illinois University-Edwardsville.

What could I understand here? Is Cliffton’s work still being publishing up to date? or the writer just uses the present perfect to only highlight the fact that Cliffton’s work just got published (does not mean until now)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to talk about events that happened in the past but you do not want to mention a specific time, you can use the *present perfect*. You can use it with words for *time up to now*.

So the sentence **His work has been published at thealestle.com**. means that at some time in the past, his work was published. This happened during a period of time that started in the past and goes up to now.